# Updating URL without reloading route in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular 2 app that retrieves stock quotes using a URL like http://host/stocks?symbol=AAPL

On page load, a default symbol is fetched and the url reflects this. But, if I enter a symbol the page's the input field and then click the "Get Quote" button, the results are fetched, but the url still reflects the default symbol. How do I get the url to update after fetching a new symbol?
Thanks

Comment: you'll need to add your code here for fetching and displaying the default symbol.

Comment: Are you activating a route when the user clicks the Get Quote button? That would change the URL.

Comment: No, I don't activate the route, I just fetch the quote data. Won't activating the route cause the page to reload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can use Location service to change url:

```
 /**
  * Changes the browsers URL to the normalized version of the given URL, and pushes a
 * new item onto the platform's history.
 */
 go(path: string, query: string = ''): void {
  this._platformStrategy.pushState(null, '', path, query);
 }
```

Comment: What's the type of this._platformStrategy?